# inset into pdo runs but does not insert data in database nor show errors

Tags: php, pdo, sql-insert

I believe I have done due diligence before coming to this forum. I saw some similar questions. One of them came close to my issue but it dealt with transactions. My code is much shorter and simpler. My insert into statement runs but it does not insert data to the database. And it does not show an error. So I can't see what the error is.When it runs it redirect to the header("location: home.php"); There the browser output data that I inserted manually in xampp. If anyone can help me by seeing something that I missed I'd  appreciate      it. Here is the code `session_start();

```
  require_once 'debase.php';
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  if (isset($_POST['user_name']) && !empty($_POST['user_name'])) {
  try{
  $conn = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
  $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  name(user_name,password)VALUES(:user_name,:password");
  $stmt->bindValue(1,':user_name');;
  $stmt->bindValue(2,':password');
  $stmt->execute();
  if (!$stmt) {
  echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
  print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
  }
  $stmt->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  header("location: home.php");

  }catch(PDOException $e){
  //echo $error_message = $e->getMessage();
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($stmt));
  }
  }`
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO($dsn,$username,$password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO  name(user_name,password)VALUES(:user_name,:password");
    $stmt->bindValue(1,':user_name');;
    $stmt->bindValue(2,':password');
    $stmt->execute();
    if (!$stmt) {
        echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
        print_r($dbh->errorInfo());
    }else{
        header("location: home.php");
    }
  }catch(PDOException $e){
      echo $e->getMessage();
  }`
```

Comment: Now I'm getting errors, good. But I had figure out how to fix Integrity Constraint violation. When I fixed that the password that was inserting into the database is the password I set in the database connection, not the password of the user. That's a strange one. But I'll get to the bottom of it.